# Construct a Cantor-distributed random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let  $\xi_{1},\xi_{2},\cdots$ be a sequence of independent random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbf{P})$ and identically
distributed Bernoulli  with $\mathbf{P}\{\xi_{1}=0\}=\mathbf{P}\{\xi_{1}=2\}=\frac{1}{2}.$

Prove that

1.The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\xi_n}{3^n}$ converges almost surely to some random variable $\xi$.$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\xi_n}{3^n}.$

2.The distribution function of the random variable $\xi$ is [the Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

---

I know the Cantor set $$C= \left\{ x:x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{3^n},a_n=0,2\right\}$$ and  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\xi_n}{3^n}$ is a random variable.For any $\omega \in \Omega$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\xi_n(\omega)}{3^n}\in C.$

Why the distribution function $F(x)=\mathbf{P}\{\xi(\omega)\le x\}$ is the Cantor function?

Comment: Prove that the series converges to something, then define $\xi$ as sum of the series.